How to pass multiple data into JSON.stringify
I want to get data of 2 fields UserId and Name in table Users from the server,
so I created a request to pass data using the @UserIdList parameter to the server to execute the postgresql query.
SELECT a."UserId",
       a."Name"
FROM public."Users" AS a
WHERE a."UserId" IN (@UserIdList)
ORDER BY a."UserId";

I want to get data of 3 UserIds (6,62,63) but the returned result is only UserId 63,
I have researched but don't know how to pass the data to get the data of 3 UserIds (6,62,63)
Is it possible?
If anyone has any advice I'd appreciate it. Thanks!
My current request:
// Create a request URL
const apiUrlSql = 'http://127.0.0.1/test/api/sql';
const requestDataSql = JSON.stringify({
    "ApiVersion": 1.1,
    "ApiKey": "ApiKey",
    "Name": "GetNameMultiple",
    "Params": {
        "UserIdList": (6,62,63)
    }
});     

// Create object XMLHttpRequest
const xhrSql = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Setting request
xhrSql.open('POST', apiUrlSql, true);
xhrSql.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

// Process request
xhrSql.onload = function() {
    if (xhrSql.readyState == 4 && xhrSql.status == 200) {
        // successful
        const responseJson = JSON.parse(xhrSql.responseText);
        console.log(responseJson);

    } else {
        // failed
        console.error('Request error:', xhrSql.statusText);
    }
};
// Run request
xhrSql.send(requestDataSql);



Serialize the list of identifiers. Use
"Params": {
        "UserIdList": "{6,62,63}"
    }

and
SELECT a."UserId",
       a."Name"
FROM public."Users" AS a
WHERE a."UserId" = any(@UserIdList::integer[])
ORDER BY a."UserId";

Unrelated but using uppercase letters in column names is not a good idea in PostgreSQL.

Amazingly it worked! Thank you for your guidance. I will change the column names to lowercase letters.
